# Redirect all frontend pages to admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml

I want to "disable" frontend in Magento and use only admin interface. So every non-admin page should be redirect to /admin (/admin/dashboard)

I can't find way to do it.

.

Comment: that might seem like a stupid question, but why?

Comment: To clarify,
I am using magento as framework for my custom application that is not an eshop / ecommerce. So i am using only backend and when for whatever reason non-admin url shows up i want to redirect it to admin part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case,you need use ***controller_action_predispatch*** event on

on this event you need redirection to  admin url.

**using  below code:**

> ```
>        $url=   Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/index/login');
>
>            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
>                       ->setRedirect($url)
>                                 ->sendResponse();
> ```

**condition:** *Current store is admin* .Check by code: if `Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()`

### Config.xml code:

> ```
> <global>
> ...
>   <models>
>     <magento85915>
>       <class>StackOverflow_Magento85915_Model</class>
>     </magento85915>
>   </models>
>     <events>
>     <controller_action_predispatch> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
>         <observers>
>           <controller_action_predispatch_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
>             <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
>             <class>magento85915/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
>             <method>adminRedirection</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
>           </controller_action_predispatch_handler>
>         </observers>
>       </controller_action_predispatch>
>     </events>
>   </global>
> ```

### observer code:

> ```
> <?php
> class StackOverflow_Magento85915_Model_Observer
> {
>
>           public function adminRedirection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
>           {
>               $controller_action= $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
>               $request=$controller_action->getRequest();
>
>               // redirection fire when current store is not aadmin
>               if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()):
>               // Get admin log page url
>                $url=   Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/index/login');
>               /* forcefull redirection  to admin login page */
>                    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
>                               ->setRedirect($url)
>                                         ->sendResponse();
>                         exit;
>                   endif;
>               return true;
>         }
>
>
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried add code directly to Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front but it's called even on admin pages and i am getting too many redirects error by browser

Comment: ok. i  will check..

Comment: please check.. answered update.

Comment: Thank you sir,
worked like charm !